# Any idea how to use ng-repeat and ng-switch together?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an issue when I am trying to use `ng-options` and `ng-switch` together in AngularJS. Any idea how to use `ng-repeat` and `ng-switch` together?

Comment: Question is `ng-options` with `ng-switch` or `ng-repeat` with `ng-switch` or both?

Comment: ng-options with ng-switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an `on` directive on your `ng-repeat` like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="..." ng-switch on="item.itemType" >
```

Then inside your repeater you can evaluate the expression inside the `on` directive like so:

```
<my-type ng-switch-when='1' >
```

`ng-switch-when` will be evaluated against the `on` directive in the repeater. If the statement evaluates to true, it will be rendered.

In this example `item.itemType` would need to have a value of 1 to be rendered out.

For `ng-options` however using an `ng-switch` doesn't make any sense as you can't include any custom html inside a `select`. If you need a `filter` or a `group by` you can do that in the `ng-options` expression directly.

See the docs here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions